# concatenating an element of array in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, pattern-matching

I have a script in which I am attempting to match strings in filenames on either side of a word.  The keywords which are meant for pattern matchin with the wildcard character, as in:

`ls *spin*.txt`

This will of course match any of the following filenames:

`one_spin.txt`
`4_5342spin-yyy.txt`
`fifty_spinout.txt`

...etc.

What I would like to do is use the word 'spin' and a number of other words as match cases in an array that I can pass through a loop.  I'd like these matches to be *case-insensitive* I attempt this like so:

```
types=(spin wheel rotation)

for file in $types; do
    ls '*'${file}'*.txt'
done
```

**EDIT:** Because I'm looking for a solution that is maleable, I'd also like to be able to do something like:

```
types=(spin wheel rotation)

for file in $types; do
    find . -iname "*$file*.txt"
done
```

I'm not sure how bash interprets either of these except seeing that it does not list the desired files.  Can someone clarify what is happening in my script, and offer a solution that meets the aforementioned criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt will work with a little more tweaks. As you are assigning `types`
as an array, you need to access it as an array.
Would you please try:

```
types=(spin wheel rotation)

for file in "${types[@]}"; do
    ls *${file}*.txt
done
```

If your `bash` supports `shopt` builtin, you can also say:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls *@(spin|wheel|rotation)*.txt
```

If you want to make it match in a case-insensitive way, please try:

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
ls *@(spin|wheel|rotation)*.txt
```

which will match `one_Spin.txt`, `fifty_SPINOUT.TXT`, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you - I need to study the `shopt` built-in.  I'd seen the `extglob` option and I don't fully understand what it affords a `.sh` script, pattern-wise.  Found a decent overview here: https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/13126/extended-globbing

Comment: what if I want to match and have it be case-insensitive?  Something like `echo find . -iname *${file}*.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Surely `find . -iname "*$file*.txt"` does work. you can also make use of `shopt -s nocaseglob` as well. Please take a
look of my updated answer. BR.

Answer (score 0):

don't make it complicate please try this instead

```
ls *{spin,wheel,rotation}*.txt
```

This also helpfull in creating files

```
touch 1_{spin,wheel,rotation,ads,sad,zxc}_2.txt
```

Or dirs

```
mkdir -p {test,test2/log,test3}
```